# Is it possible to set Doctrine parameter in doctrine.yaml (or doctrine.php) dynamically?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony6

I'm using a Doctrine filter to limit the result set to the logged in user's records (ie `where user_id = <their id>`). I'm wondering if this can only be done adding parameters to the Doctrine filter programmatically, or can I do it dynamically in the config\packages\doctrine.yaml (or config\packages\doctrine.php) file.

The filter parameter is being set in the Controller programmatically as follows:

```
config/packages/doctrine.yaml:
...
        filters:
            user_filter:
              class: App\Doctrine\UserFilter
              enabled: true
```

```
src\Doctrine\UserFilter.php:
public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias): string
    {
        if ($targetEntity->getReflectionClass()->name == 'App\Entity\Task') {
            $mypar = $this->getParameter('user_id');
            return sprintf('%s.user_id = %s', $targetTableAlias, $mypar );
        }
        return '';
    }
```

```
src/TaskController.php:
class TaskController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'app_task_index', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function index(TaskRepository $taskRepository, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        // Add the user_id filter to the Doctrine filter
        // First get the filter, then set the required parameter on it
        $userFilter = $entityManager->getFilters()->getFilter('user_filter');
        $userFilter->setParameter('user_id', $this->getUser()->getId());

        return $this->render('task/index.html.twig', [
            'tasks' => $taskRepository->findAll(),
        ]);
    }
```

Setting the Doctrine filter parameter like this works but it needs the EntityManagerInterface to be passed in so we can access the entity manager.

I would like to be able to set the parameter using the Symfony 6.2 Doctrine filter config that allows us to pass the parameters in the configuration file:

```
config/packages/doctrine.yaml
...
        filters:
            user_filter:
              class: App\Doctrine\UserFilter
              enabled: true
                  parameters: $user->getUser()->getId()   << this doesn't work
```

I tried converting the doctrine config to PHP thinking it might allow interpreted code:

config/packages/doctrine.php:

```
           'filters' => [
                'user_filter' => [
                    'class' => UserFilter::class,
                    'enabled' => true,
                    'parameters' => [
                        'user_id' => $this->getUser()->getId(), << this doesn't work
                    ],
```

This gives error Using $this when not in object context.

Is it possible to get the logged in user id in the configuration like this, or is it too late (is the config in the above way only for static information)? Is the way I've coded parameters the most appropriate way to do this?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider to leveradge from an event listener like

```
namespace App\Doctrine\EventListener;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;

class UserCreateListener
{
    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $args): void
    {
        // if this listener may apply to user entity type only,
        $targetEntity = $args->getClassMetadata();
        if ($targetEntity->getReflectionClass()->name !== User::class) {
            return;
        }

        // enables filter (service) 'user_filter' and set parameters
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
        $conn = $entityManager->getConnection();
        $sql = 'SELECT id FROM <database>';
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $result = $stmt->executeQuery()->fetchAssociative();
        $filter = $entityManager->getFilters()->enable('user_filter');
        $filter->setParameter('user_id', $result['id']);
    }
}
```

Registration of the service in services.yaml could be like:

```
App\Doctrine\EventListener\UserCreateListener:
    tags:
        -   name: doctrine.event_listener
            # this is the only required option for the lifecycle listener tag
            event: 'loadClassMetadata'
            # listeners can define their priority in case multiple subscribers or listeners are associated
            # to the same event (default priority = 0; higher numbers = listener is run earlier)
            priority: 512
            # you can also restrict listeners to a specific Doctrine connection
            connection: 'default'
```

For further information look at:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-listeners